# Ive recently changed to a JTextPane and my load feature has broken

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, loading, jtextpane

My load feature requires me to append the TextPane
here is my current load featue

```
private void loadFile() {
        String line;
        File file;
        JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
        if (dialog.showOpenDialog(text) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = dialog.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                 try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                     text.setText("");
                     line = input.readLine();
                     while (line != null) {
                       text.append(line + "\n");
                       line = input.readLine();
                     }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(text, "Can't load file "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

the issue is the appending part and i cant find a fix

Comment: which is the error message?

Comment: @LucasZ.: JTextPane does not have a `setText(...)` method.

Answer (score 2):

Again, use the JTextComponent's `read(...)` method as this will read the text file right into your text component.

```
try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    text.read(input, "Text File");
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The GUI updates code (like `text.setText("");`) should be running in the GUI-thread (EDT), while the CPU-time consuming code (like `line = input.readLine();`) should be running in background threads. Read more about [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and also read this Java tutorial:

- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).